# failed to upload multiple files simultaneously into mysql database using jsp and java

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I am trying to upload multiple files simultaneously but my code is uploading only one file into MySQL database even if I select multiple files while uploading. There is one folder named as "resources" in my code. So when I click on submit button with multiple files selected for uploading then all files are storing into "resources" folder but among all files only one record is shown in database. Please help me where I am getting wrong. I searched for this answer from 2 weeks.

Here is my code.. UploadServletClass.java.

```js
package com.servlets;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;
import com.servlet.db.DB;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@WebServlet(name = "UploadServletClass", urlPatterns = {
  "/UploadServletClass"
})
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 10, //10MB
  maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1000, //1GB
  maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1000) //1GB
public class UploadServletClass extends HttpServlet {
  PrintWriter out = null;
  Connection con = null;
  PreparedStatement ps = null;
  HttpSession session = null;

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
      out = response.getWriter();
      session = request.getSession(false);
      String folderName = "resources";
      //String uploadPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + folderName;
      String uploadPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + folderName;
      File dir = new File(uploadPath);
      if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
      }

      // Part filepart = request.getPart("file");
      String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
      String lastName = request.getParameter("lastname");
      String fileName = "";

      String path = folderName + File.separator + fileName;
      Timestamp added_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
      String div = request.getParameter("division"); //textbox value of division field
      String repunit = request.getParameter("reportingunit"); //textbox value of reportingunit field
      String docnum = request.getParameter("documentnumber"); //textbox value of documentnumber field
      String docName = request.getParameter("documentname"); //textbox value of documentname field
      String docUploader = request.getParameter("documentuploader"); //textbox value of documentuploader field
      String docOwner = request.getParameter("documentowner"); //textbox value of documentowner field
      String docType = request.getParameter("Document_Type"); //textbox value of Document_Type field
      String docCategory = request.getParameter("Document_Category"); //textbox value of Document_Category field

      System.out.println("filename:" + fileName);
      System.out.println("path:" + uploadPath);
      System.out.println("Name:" + firstName);

      try {
        con = DB.getConnection();
        System.out.println("connection done");

        List < Part > fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part - > "file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (Part filePart: fileParts) {
          // fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
          fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
          //fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
          filePart.write(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName);
          InputStream ins = filePart.getInputStream();
          String sql = "insert into newfiles(firstname,lastname,filename,path,division,reportingunit,documentnumber,documentname,documentuploader,documentowner,documenttype,documentcategory,added_date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; //inserting all values into database
          ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
          Files.copy(ins, Paths.get(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }


        ps.setString(1, firstName);
        ps.setString(2, lastName);
        ps.setString(3, fileName);
        ps.setString(4, path);
        ps.setString(5, div); //index specifies the respective parameter in the query
        ps.setString(6, repunit);
        ps.setString(7, docnum);
        ps.setString(8, docName);
        ps.setString(9, docUploader);
        ps.setString(10, docOwner);
        ps.setString(11, docType);
        ps.setString(12, docCategory);
        ps.setTimestamp(13, added_date);
        int status = ps.executeUpdate();
        if (status > 0) {
          session.setAttribute("filename", fileName);
          String msg = " File Uploaded Successfully...";
          request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
          RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/process.jsp");
          rd.forward(request, response);
          System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");
          System.out.println("Uploaded Path:" + uploadPath);



        }
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        out.println("Exception:" + e);
        System.out.println("Exception1:" + e);

      } finally {
        try {
          if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
          }
          if (con != null) {
            con.close();
          }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
          out.println(e);
        }
      }



    } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
      out.println("Exception:" + e);
      System.out.println("Exception2:" + e);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: please help....

Comment: _only one record is shown in database_ - that's logical, because you call the INSERT statement only once. If you want to do it for all files, put it inside the `for (Part filePart: fileParts) {` cycle (do `getConnection()` and `prepareStatement()` before the cycle, then all the `ps.setString()` etc. and `ps.executeUpdate()` within the cycle).

Comment: @JozefChocholacek  as per you said, I have done changes in code and also edited above code but not working.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still calling `executeUpdate()` just once. Here what I would do (just the `try` block, the rest is more or less OK):

```
  try {
    con = DB.getConnection();
    System.out.println("connection done");

    List < Part > fileParts = request.getParts().stream().filter(part - > "file".equals(part.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    String sql = "insert into newfiles(firstname,lastname,filename,path,division,reportingunit,documentnumber,documentname,documentuploader,documentowner,documenttype,documentcategory,added_date) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; //inserting all values into database
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    int counter = 0;
    for (Part filePart: fileParts) {
      // fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
      fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
      //fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();
      filePart.write(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName);
      InputStream ins = filePart.getInputStream();
      Files.copy(ins, Paths.get(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
      ps.setString(1, firstName);
      ps.setString(2, lastName);
      ps.setString(3, fileName);
      ps.setString(4, path);
      // all the other ps.setXY calls
      int status = ps.executeUpdate();
      if (status > 0) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Successfully uploaded file #" + counter + ", uploaded path:" + uploadPath);
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    }

    if (counter > 0) {
      String msg = "Successfully uploaded " + counter + " files.";
      request.setAttribute("msg", msg);
      System.out.println(msg);
      session.setAttribute("filename", fileName); // this is just the last file name, does it make sense?
    }
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/process.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);

  } catch (SQLException e) {
  ...
```

I.e. you have to INSERT a DB record for **each** uploaded file. Btw. I would recommend to re-design your DB and have one table for documents, and a second table for files, using 1:N relation between documents and files.

Comment: Thank you so much man. Heartly thank you... you helped me to solve my issue. I was trying since 2 weeks. thank u again :)